# Protractor integration with frisby API

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to integrate frisby api with protractor.

```
    // An example configuration file.
exports.config = {

 //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/SpecFiles/frisby_global_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }

};
```

//The Spec File

```
   var frisby = require('frisby');

var base_url = "https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/test-your-nodejs-with-jasmine";

describe("Hello World Server", function() {
    it("first frisbytest", function () {
        frisby.create('GET JSON data from an endpoint')
            .get(base_url)
            .expectStatus(200)
            .expectHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .toss();

    });

});
```

but i am getting below error

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1125:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/SpecFiles/frisby_global_spec.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:84:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:83:18)
    at Jasmine.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:176:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:119:15
    at Function.promise `enter code here`(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:91:14
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
[10:12:38] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

i am new to javascript testing.please let me know is it frisby api and protractor integration possible or not. if yes can you please help to debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error which you are observing is due to Protractor supports jasmine2 by default but frisby currently is not compatible with jasmine2, it only supports jasmine1 as of now hence you cannot use the native frisby components with protractor.

**Work Around:** I recently managed to integrate protractor with frisby as jasmine2 support is coming up for it, right now there is good work on this which is being provided in a separate PR and branch in frisby github repo.

You can use some of the functionality of frisby with protractor with this work around but full support will be coming soon!

So you can checkout my repo- [protractor-frisby](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-frisby) on how to integrate protractor with frisby with this work around.

**Note:** This provides only limited support as of now, soon full support should coming out!